# curl: (26) couldn't open file when the file is a variable

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to upload a list of files to a server. This is the script that I have

```
files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo /media/USB/*) > /dev/null 2>&1
if (( ${#files}  ))
    then
            for file in $files
            do
                    echo "Filename"
                    echo $file
                    curl -i -X POST -F files=@$file 192.168.1.122:5000/upload
            done
```

Basically I am trying to take all of the files on a USB drive and upload them to my local server. The curl command is giving me trouble. I can move these files to drives that I mount on this system but I haven't been able to send them with the curl command. I have tried variations on `@"$file"` and `@\"$file\"` based on other related questions but I haven't been able to get this to work. However what is annoying is that when I do this:

```
curl -i -X POST -F files=@/absolute/path/to/my/file.txt 192.168.1.122:5000/upload
```

It works as I expect. How can I get this to work in my loop?

Comment: One thing to consider is the location off of where the script is running versus the location of the files. The way you're acquiring the filenames is through "echo /media/USB/*" which will get you a filename but not an absolute path. Is your script running off of /media/USB? If not, you will need to get the absolute path so that this works.

Comment: You might be onto something... The script is not running in "/media/USB/" However when I echo the filepath it is the absolute path. "/media/USB/filename.txt" is the "$file" however when I tested it I actually went to the directory "/media/USB" and ran the command typing in the files. there. By absolute path do you mean UNC path?

Comment: /media/usb/filename.txt Being absolute and filename.txt being relative.

Comment: My mistake though, "echo /media/usb/*" will get you absolute paths.

Comment: I guess it's the option should be "file=@..." without "s" (not "files").

Comment: The "files=@..." matches the name of the request that the server is looking for. I have it looking for files. Plus it works with a single file with the "files" name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out a solution that I will share in case anyone else is having this problem. I am not sure exactly why this fixed it but I simply had to put quotes around the `files=@$file` in the curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -F "files=@$file" 192.168.1.122:5000/upload
```

Leaving this here in case it is useful to someone down the line.

Comment: Also I guess `@rudi` kind of mentioned this in his comment

Comment: Curiously enough, I had an opposite situation: in  `for file in /my_folder/*.jpg; do echo $file; time curl -X POST http://my_server/my_endpoint -F media=@$file; done` I had to remove quotes to make it see the file!

Comment: Similar to @alisa removing the quotes also worked for me in a windows environment using curl.exe, digging into the man page for curl points to an interesting tidbit as to why this works:


`Note that if a filename/path is quoted by double-quotes, any double-quote or backslash within the filename must be escaped by backslash.` 


So if you are referencing an absolute windows path especially with a ',' or ';' you'll need to double quotes and also escape your backslashes (\\), if you don't have commas or semi-colons removing the quotes remove the need to escape the backslash.